# MacOs enabeling php-zip and getting Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0 error

Tags: php, macos, macos-catalina

After installing `php-zip` with `pecl`, this installer command added `extension=zip.so` in end of `php.ini` file, now when i try to install a php script i get `current = Off`. restarting `apache` couldn't resolve my problem and i think i don't have another installed php on my system.

after uncommenting `extension=zip.so` this command `php --init` return this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

```
sudo pecl install zip
Password:
PHP Warning:  Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module "zip" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
pecl/zip is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.20.0
```

how can i resolve this problem?

Comment: What's the problem?  You have "zip" installed, so you don't need to install it again.

Comment: @TimRoberts i get this warning for zip: `Current :Off  required On` when i try to install php script

Comment: Does `sudo phpenmod zip` do it?

Comment: @TimRoberts it doesn't work `sudo: phpenmod: command not found`